# Is it possible to use face landmark solution from Mediapipe to generate face mesh in Android java project independently?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, mediapipe, face-mesh

I'm working on a face tracking application (Android studio / Java) and I need to identify face landmarks and show face mesh's specific points. I'm interested using [Mediapipe face mesh solution](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/docs/solutions/face_mesh.md#face-landmark-model). The problem is: I use Windows OS, and Mediapipe is not working on Windows OS. I don't want to use [bazel](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/hello_world_android) to create android application. I want to use mediapipe inside my application.

Can anybody explain to me how can i use Mediapipe's face_landmark solution to detect faces in images and generate face mesh inside exisiting Android studio with Java application. And If there is a solution with models like face_landmark.tflite, please explain me how can I use such tflite independently inside my application without the whole Mediapipe framework?

I want to use mediapipe face mesh solution inside my android studio java application in order to get specific face landmark points to acheive my task.